# Gettings all keys from 2nd level of 3 levels map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > > SCHEMA;

int main() {
    SCHEMA schema;

    // Schema table
    schema["table1"]["field1"]["type"] = "int";
    schema["table1"]["field2"]["type"] = "bool";
    schema["table2"]["field1"]["type"] = "int";
}
```

How can i get the names of fields for table1?

I would like to have something like this:

```
fields = array(
 0 => "field1",
 1 => "field2"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run trough all the keys with a simple `for` ranged loop (C++11):

```
std::vector<std::string> fields;
for (const auto& f : schema["table1"])
    fields.emplace_back(f.first);
```

or, if you do not have access to the C++11 features, with iterators:

```
std::vector<std::string> fields;
for (SCHEMA::const_iterator it = schema["table1"].cbegin(); it != schema["table1"].cend(); ++it)
    fields.push_back(it->first);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could also tell me what is it the "auto"?